# I'm trying to create a database but i keep getting the same error, and according to me and my fellow students the code is fine

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

This is just an example, from the first 2 tables but I get the same error:

MySQL said: Documentation

`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 10`

```
CREATE TABLE Tallas
(
IDTalla int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
descripcion varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (IDTalla),
)

CREATE TABLE Modelo
(
IDModelo int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
IDTalla int NOT NULL,
modeloNombre varchar(45) NOT NULL,
precio varchar(45) NOT NULL,
informacion varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (IDModelo),
FOREIGN KEY (IDTalla) REFERENCES Modelo(IDTalla),
)
```

Comment: at the end "Modelo(IDTalla), )" ... seems to be missing something or that comma should not be there

Comment: Those commas are trouble for sure.

Comment: Please use snake_case for identifiers, for future generations

Answer (score 7):

Remove the coma at `PRIMARY KEY (IDTalla)`, to make it `PRIMARY KEY (IDTalla)`

and the same with `REFERENCES Modelo(IDTalla),`

Comment: also...is the version of sql of your computer in spanish (or italian) ? I tried to run your query and the parsing stops at "desripcion", "informacion" etc...but your error message is in English ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma -> (IDTalla),)  (IDTalla))

Comment: Beat me to it JFPicard.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you put an extra comma in your create table statement just after primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE Tallas ( 
  IDTalla int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  descripcion varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (IDTalla), 
)
```

This should be:

```
CREATE TABLE Tallas ( 
  IDTalla int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  descripcion varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (IDTalla) 
)
```

Same with the second statement.